# Memento pattern lack

Tags: c#, design-patterns, memento

in my project about image processing I need to have Undo/Redo button.
Briefly saying I do multiple operations on Bitmaps which then I assign to picturebox.
I found this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10576/An-Undo-Redo-Buffer-Framework
I created my Originator based on the one from example code.

It looks like that

```
class Originator : ISupportMemento
{
    private Bitmap state;
    public IMemento Memento
    {
        get
        {
            Memento mcm = new Memento();
            mcm.State = GetMyState();
            return mcm;
        }
        set
        {
            SetMyState(value.State);
        }
    }

    protected object GetMyState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    protected void SetMyState(object newstate)
    {
        state = (Bitmap)newstate;
    }

}
```

But when i am trying to assing a bitmap object to it, Compilator is messaging an error.

```
    UndoBuffer bufferr = new UndoBuffer();
    Originator orig;
    orig.Memento = (object)_baseimg;
```

Could you please help me, very sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Cannot convert obcject to IMemento.

Comment: If you want to assign a value to a property having the type `IMemento`, you have to use an object that is of that type. Assuming `_baseimg` is of type `Bitmap`, there's no way you can assign that object to `Memento`, even casting it to `object` (which accomplishes nothing). You need to create a `Memento` object (assuming it implements `IMemento`), set _its_ state to your `_baseimg` value, set the `IMemento.Action` property as appropriate, and then assign that `Memento` object to the property.